# How to check If method is executed?

Tags: c#

I need to prevent some methods execution when an other method is executed  that's why i think to check if that last did. The problem i didn't find a helpful solution, any ideas please.

```
private void LoadScenarioNumber()
{
        //some code
}

private void NumberOfScenariosChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   //if LoadScenarioNumber() is excuted
       return;
   else
       UpdateScenarioDataGrid();

}
```

Comment: Have you thought about adding a member variable to your class that will keep this information?

Comment: I would imagine there is some meaningful/predictable *side-effect* of `LoadScenarioNumber` that can be used to determine if it "has been loaded/run" ..

Comment: Perhaps if you expanded on what the actual design issue is, we might be able to give something more meaningful and not monstrously hackish like the current suggestions! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply set a global boolean value in your method like this:

```
private bool loadScenarioNumberExecuted = false;

private void LoadScenarioNumber()
{
    //some code
    loadScenarioNumberExecuted = true;
}

private void NumberOfScenariosChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (loadScenarioNumberExecuted)
         return;        

    UpdateScenarioDataGrid();

}
```

As an alternative you could use a state driven pattern where you have an enumeration of possible states and assign the current state to a global variable.

For more information on state driven programming you can read the following article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509234/The-State-Design-Pattern-vs-State-Machine

Comment: I won't -1 this as it is pretty much like the rest of the answers, but it definitely has a smell around it...

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool executed;
private void LoadScenarioNumber()
{
        //some code

        executed = true;
}

private void NumberOfScenariosChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (executed)
       return;
   else
       UpdateScenarioDataGrid();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isExecuted = false;

private void LoadScenarioNumber()
{
   // your code
   isExecuted = true;
}

private void NumberOfScenariosChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (isExecuted) 
    return;
  else
     UpdateScenarioDataGrid();

}
```

Comment: don't forget to set the isExecuted back on false ==> later use of the variable will always return true now

Comment: It depends on the action though, he may want to use it only once, otherwise yea, there must be a set to true.

Comment: I do not believe this is a good way to solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you use a, for example, `bool _scenarioNumberLoaded = false`, to check if a certain piece of code is executed.

Comment: Looks like envious downvote. Answer is good, +1 (but I think field should be initialized with `false`)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your first function updates the scenario grid based on the numbers (when loading from, say, disk), and the event handler is responding to user-input and updates the grid in the same fashion, and you are trying to avoid calling that update-function twice.

A far cleaner solution imho would be to have the LoadScenariosNumber populate the control that contains this, and then theoretically the event will be raised to notify listeners that it has and therefore the scenario grid will be updated as if the user had changed the control themselves.

This is a much more fluid, less error-prone method then setting global variables in an attempt to track what has been updated, and when.